# Two Jumping Rings Go Higher than One. Why?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction

When I do the [Thomson's jumping ring](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=thomson's+jumping+ring) demo with one aluminum ring it rises up in the air to some height.  When I place two identical rings on top of each other and repeat the demo, both rings rise considerably higher than the single ring.  Why?  Is there additional current induced in each ring due to the other ring?  How would you calculate the size of this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Please refer this(248KB)

http://www.google.co.in/url?q=https://www.grinnell.edu/sites/default/files/documents/tjossem_and_brost_optimizing_thomsons_jumping_ring.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjftbLBhf7LAhXHlIMKHfb_DMsQFggQMAI&sig2=bRAhzy_nVpZXcDXFxWRM7Q&usg=AFQjCNHpNH-thwGNyNqOvlm9e_8gRTxNBw

$\frac{h}{h°}=\frac{m°}{m} \frac{2}{m°/m(\rho°/\rho)^2 +1}$

which tells up to a optimal mass of m°, h increase and then decrease.

Reference
1) Am. J. Phys., Vol.79, No.4, April 2011
2) P.J.H. Tjossem and E.C. Brost

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: @Qmechanic I dont know all that. I just googled and found PDF directly. I even saw no website to it.

Comment: I wrote what I found on PDF. Is it okay?